# ¿Como cargar archivos CSS de forma dinamica usando PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

En lo personal esto me funciona muy bien y no he tenido problemas hasta el momento

pero si me gustaría saber de que forma puedo mejorar para que sea mas dinámico o alguna opinión que tengan

Archivo **load_view.php**

Si requieres agregar más archivos CSS solo los agregas a la variable $html usando **.=** (punto y igual) como se muestra en el segundo estilo agregado.

**ruta:** *class/load_view.php*

```
<?php
class LoadHtml 
{

    public static function AutoLoad()
    {
         $html = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">';
         $html .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">';
         return $html;
    }

}
```

En en index solo creas la instancia y la mandas llamar de esta forma

```
<?php

include_once 'class/load_view.php';

$ldhtml = new LoadHtml();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php echo $ldhtml->AutoLoad(); ?>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Considerando esta estructura de esta forma creada con composer

[image: Estructura de composer]

Comment: cual es la pregunta o duda?

Comment: bueno como lo tengo me funciona pero, tener punto de vista de alguien mas nunca esta de mas.

Answer (score 1):

Tu clase actual funciona solo para archivos CSS estáticos, siempre será lo mismo, si quieres tener un poco de flexibilidad, te recomiendo crear arreglos para los diferentes tipos de recursos a cargar. En este ejemplo solo tomé en cuenta hojas de estilos y archivos Javascript.

```
<?php
class LoadHtml 
{
    // Arreglos para archivos CSS y Javascript
    private $_css = [
        'vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'css/estilo.css',
    ];
    private $_js = [
        // Aquí agrega los scripts de tu proyecto
    ];
    public function __construct() {}
    // Agregar hoja de estilos
    public function addCss($file) {
        // Evitar duplicados
        if(!in_array($file, $this->_css)) {
            $this->_css[] = $file;
        }
    }
    // Agregar archivo Javascript
    public function addJs($file) {
        // Evitar duplicados
        if(!in_array($file, $this->_js)) {
            $this->_js[] = $file;
        }
    }
    public function getCss() {
         $html = '';
         forEach($this->_css as $css) {
             $html .= "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$css\">";
         }
         return $html;
    }
    public function getJs() {
         $html = '';
         forEach($this->_js as $js) {
             $html .= "<script src=\"$js\"></script>";
         }
         return $html;
    }
}
```

Después lo usas como hasta ahora, solo cambiando el nombre de los métodos:

```
<?php
include_once 'class/load_view.php';
$ldhtml = new LoadHtml();
// Aquí puedes agregar otros archivos CSS o JS, de ser necesario    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php echo $ldhtml->getCss(); ?>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Resto de tu código -->
<!-- Agregar scripts -->
<?php echo $ldhtml->getJs(); ?>
<!-- Fin de página -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me gusta en realidad funciona como lo tengo pero si como comentas tener mayor flexibilidad, tomare tu ejemplo mucho en cuenta para mis proyectos, muchas gracias